# Helix SharpDx toolkit not accessible in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, f#, sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

I am porting an example from C# to F# working with the sharpDX helix toolkit. I downloaded with nuget all the references so that the two projects have the same references and copied over the XAML code but I have an error saying that "the name x does not exist in the namespace 'http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf/SharpDX'". Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

xaml code :

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:hx="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf/SharpDX"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ie="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
Title="{Binding Title}"
Width="800"
Height="500"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Window.Resources>
    <hx:RenderTechniqueConverter x:Key="RenderTechniqueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

the "RenderTechniqueConverter" has the error and generally anywhere I reference hx.
Thanks

Comment: I know nothing about sharpDX, but I wonder if the `hx:RenderTechniqueConverter` line in your `Window.Resources` section should have been `x:RenderTechniqueConverter`? I.e., replace `hx` with `x`.

Comment: @rmunn Then I have  "'RenderTechniqueConverter' is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. My mistake, I was missing a reference to "HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX". When I downloaded that everything was fine. Hope this helps someone.